# How to split() string with brackets in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

i just want to make

```
str = "a(bcde(dw)d)e"
```

to

```
arr = {"a", "(bcde)", "(dw)", "(d)", "e"}
```

What regEx can i use in `str.split()`?

PS: Explanations || helpful links welcome.

Examples:

```
s: "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q" --> [ 'a', '(bcdefghijkl)', '(mno)', '(p)', 'q' ]
s: "abc(cba)ab(bac)c" --> [ 'abc', '(cba)', 'ab', '(bac)', 'c' ]
```

Comment: your result looks a bit strange || invalid.

Comment: Is the result supposed to be an array of strings, `["a", "(bcde)", "(dw)", "(d)", "e"]`?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be an array of strings.

Comment: Can you add a few edge cases? What about "a(b)c(d)e"? What about "(a(b)c(d)e)"?

Comment: What about "(a(b(c)))d(e)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go through each parentheses using a counter:

```js
array = [], c = 0;

'abc(cba)ab(bac)c'.split(/([()])/).filter(Boolean).forEach(e =>
// Increase / decrease counter and push desired values to an array
e == '(' ? c++ : e == ')' ? c-- : c > 0 ? array.push('(' + e + ')') : array.push(e)
);

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Note: This is ES6 syntax and will not work as is in older browsers

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

```js
str = "a(bcde(dw)d)e"
    // replace any `(alpha(` by `(alpha)(`
    str1 = str.replace(/\(([^)]+)\(/g, '($1)(');
    // replace any `)alpha)` by )(alpha)`
    str2 = str1.replace(/\)([^(]+)\)/g, ')($1)');
    // prefix any opening parenthesis with #--# (just a character string unlikly to appear in the original string)
    str3 = str2.replace(/\(/g, '#--#(');
    // prefix any closing parenthesis with  #--#
    str4 = str3.replace(/\)/g, ')#--#');
    // remove any double `#--#`
    str5 = str4.replace(/(#--#)+/g, '#--#');
    // split by invented character string
    arr = str5.split('#--#');
    console.log(arr);
```

### Old wrong answer

```js
    str = "a(bcde(dw)d)e"
    console.log(str.split(/[()]/));
```

This looks a little bit weird, but it's like this.

str is string which has a `split` method. This can take a string or a regular expression as argument. A string will be delimited by `"` and a RegExp by `/`.
The brackets `[]` wrap a character class which means any one of the characters inside. Then inside we have the two parentheses `()` which are the two characters we are looking for.

Comment: The result of this answer is [a,bcde,dw,d,e]. Not exactly what the OP was looking for...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the result you want is possible without modifying the values of the array after the split. But if you want to be able to split the string based on 2 symbols (in this case the brackets '(' and ')') you can do this:

```
var arr = str.split("(").toString().split(")");
```

It returns an array with the "words" of the string.

I hope I could help.

Comment: Suggest using str.split("{").join('').split(")") to avoid additional comma created by toString()

Answer (score 0):

Given that the desired output includes characters that aren't in the string, e.g., adding closing or opening parentheses to the substrings in the outer part of the nested parentheses, it will be necessary to make some changes to the individual substrings after they are extracted one way or another.

Maybe something like this:

```js
function getGroups(str) {
  var groups = str.match(/(?:^|[()])[^()]+/g)
  if (!groups) return []
  var parenLevel = 0
  return groups.map(function(v) {
    if (v[0] === "(") {
      parenLevel++
    } else if (v[0] === ")") {
      parenLevel--
    }
    v = v.replace(/[()]/,"")
    return parenLevel > 0 ? "(" + v + ")" : v
  })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify( getGroups("a(bcde(dw)d)e") ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( getGroups("abc(cba)ab(bac)c") ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( getGroups("ab(cd)ef(gh)") ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( getGroups("ab(cd)(e(f(gh)i))") ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( getGroups("(ab(c(d))ef(gh)i)") ))
```

Comment: for str: "abc(cba)ab(bac)c"  it  gives me   [ 'abc', '(cba)', '(ab)', '(bac)', 'c' ].

Comment: Ah. OK, I've whipped up something a little different (see my edit). I don't have time to test it properly, but it seems OK for the few cases I tried.